# How to parse nquad document

Tags: node.js, parsing, wikipedia, dbpedia

I'm interested in parsing out names of places from DBPedia's nquad document. Here's a preview: http://downloads.dbpedia.org/preview.php?file=3.8_sl_en_sl_geo_coordinates_en.nq.bz2

I've looked on Google, but haven't been able to find anything. Any suggestions? I'd prefer a nodejs module (so I can go through the code), but any tool works.

Comment: DBPedia's data is represented in RDF, so that might be a useful search term.  Searching on Google for `"nquad" nodejs` turns up [rdfquads](https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/rdfquads).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That package has a dependency that npm isn't able to find. So I googled for rdf, and found https://github.com/danmactough/node-feedparser. But I'm not sure how to use it. Could you give a code snippet?